# Hide already selected items jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete to allow users to search and select multiple items when completing a form. Once an item has been selected it is possible for the user to remove the item from the list of selected items.

What I would like to be able to do is hide a selected item from future searches and show the item in future searches should the item be removed:

This is my current script:

```
var commissioner = [];

$.getJSON('/Commissioner/AutocompleteSearch')
    .done(function (data) {
        commissioner = data;
        $('#commissioner').autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(commissioner, request.term);
                response(results.slice(0, 10));
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val('');
                var li = '<li>';
                li += '<input type="hidden" name="CommissionerId" value="' + ui.item.id + '" />'
                li += ui.item.label + '<span class="delete">Delete</span>';
                li += '</li>';
                $('#selectedCommissioners').append(li);
                $('#selectedCommissioners li.none').hide();
                return false;
            }
        })
    });

$('#selectedCommissioners').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var $el = $(this).parent();
    $el.remove();

    if ($('#selectedCommissioners li').length == 1) {
        $('#selectedCommissioners li.none').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your source function you should run another `filter` on the result set, removing the results that are already in your selection. So you probably want to keep a collection of the selected values in the format that you get in your result set so they are 1:1 comparable